# ¿Por qué se dice "si me saliera" y no "si me saldría"?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, verbo-pronominal, condicional, futuro

El usuario Gustavson (profesor de Español y traductor literario entre otras cosas) me señaló en un comentario que se dice "si me saliera" y no "si me saldría". Busqué una explicación para esto y lo único que encontré es que el verbo salir es pronominal, (se puede conjugar usando me, te, nos, os, se) y que la forma saldría existe en la conjugaciones y es la forma conocida como condicional, potential simple o futuro hipotético. La forma saliera figura como pretérito imperfecto, pretérito, futuro o futuro hipotético (me llamó la atención también que la conjugación tanto de saldría como saliera figuren como distintas entradas pero ambas mencionadas en uno de sus nombres de la misma forma, futuro hipotético) [Salir](https://www.conjugarverbo.com/salir) .

También entiendo que cuando uno usa un si está hablando de una forma condicional. No dudo de lo que dice el profesor Gustavson pero no le encuentro explicación.

¿Por qué se dice "si me saliera" y no "si me saldría"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una oración condicional ("*si saliera pronto, comeríamos antes*") se divide en dos subordinadas, la *[prótasis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%B3tasis)*, que establece una hipótesis o condición ("*si saliera pronto*"), y la *[apódosis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3dosis)*, que indica la correspondiente consecuencia (*comeríamos antes*).

Algunas concordancias habituales son:

- *Si sale pronto, comemos antes*.
- *Si sale pronto, comed antes*.
- *Si saliera pronto, comeríamos antes*.
- *Si hubiera salido pronto, habríamos comido antes*.

En cualquier caso, la condición nunca va en condicional:

- *Si <s>saldría</s> pronto, comeríamos antes*, error típico en mi pueblo.

Más ejemplos y detalles en los enlaces.

Answer (score 0):

d) Aunque no estaba segura **de si me** saldría/quedaría/iba a salir igual.

Con "me"(a mi) se refiere a ella misma.

Ella misma respondiendo:

- ¿De qué no estaba segura?  R. De si **me** saldría igual. R. De si **me** quedaría igual.
- ¿Qué me preocupaba?  R. Que no **me** saliera igual(negación+imperfecto subjuntivo) R. Que no **me** quedara igual(negación+subjuntivo)
- ¿Por qué estaba preocupada? R. Porque creía que no **me** iba a salir/quedar igual.

El contexto en d) es que observó como se hacía algo y lo llevó a cabo con la duda de si le iba a salir igual de bien por su inexperiencia.

---

- e) Estaba más pendiente **de que me quedara/saliera** bien la comida que de hablar bien su idioma.

Generalmente como se muestra en e) después de "**de que**"  se usa **subjuntivo**, pero no queda claro si lo logró o no, no obstante, lo que sí sabemos es que lo hizo mejor que comunicándose.

---

- f) Aunque no estaba muy segura de **si <s>me</s> saldría** con él de nuevo.

El contexto en f) es que estaba conociendo a alguien, incluso habían salido y no estaba segura de hacerlo de nuevo en ese tiempo. En este ejemplo "me" está demás porque se trata de una cita.

- f.1) Aunque no estaba muy segura **de si saldría** con él de nuevo.

> Entonces ¿Por qué no se dice "si saliera" o "salía" en f.1)?

Porque "saldría" es para indicar una acción futura en el pasado del hablante, esa acción todavía no ocurría y tampoco había tomado una decisión si es que ésta llegaba a ocurrir.

---

- h) Insistía **en que saliera** con él

**A él vamos a llamarlo B**. En este caso B insistía que **salieran** en una cita, ambos.

- h1) Insistía **en que salía** con él.

En este caso p.ej. **su esposo tenía la sospecha** que ella **salía** con B. Difícilmente B le diría algo que ella misma hace con él mismo.

- h2) Insistía **en que saldría** con él.

En este caso p.ej. **su esposo** insistía en que creía que ella tarde o temprano **iba a salir con B** o lo haría o **el mismo B** creía que ella lo iba a hacer algún día.

---

Ahora f2) veríamos la acción como terminada, pero no en ese entonces:

- f2) Aunque no estoy muy segura **de si habría salido** con él de nuevo(si me lo hubiera pedido)

También podría decir:

- f1.1)Aunque no estaba muy segura **de salir** con él de nuevo.
- f1.2)Aunque no estaba muy segura **de si iba** a salir con él de nuevo.

---

- g4)Era (casi) **como si me saliera** de mi cuerpo.

El contexto en g4) era que algo le producía o hacía sentir algo irreal.

También podría decir:

- g4.1)Era (casi) como **salirme** de mi cuerpo
- g4.2)Era (casi) como **si me estuviera** saliendo de mi cuerpo

> Entonces ¿Por qué se dice "si me saliera" y no "si me saldría" en este ejemplo?

- d4)Era como **si me <s>saldría</s>** de mi cuerpo.

Por la estructura **como si + imperfecto de subjuntivo**, porque en realidad no se sale, es sólo la sensación que le produce.